# Java/C++ communication on Android

Tags: java, android, c++

We are trying to port our huge C++ application to Android with Java. We are also using ZeroMQ/JeroMQ library with the Google ProtoBuf one to communicate between different parts of our software.

One piece of our software will have to stay in C++, because it communicates with the external device. There the direct calls to ZeroMQ will be made and wrapped inside the C++ class.

The problem is that when I try to publish something from C++ binary with the topic "ABC", the Java subscriber will drop this message even though it is listening to the same topic "ABC".

We are developing on the RHEL 7 with Android Studio for the Java portion and Eclipse for C++.

I'm curious - is it possible that the message drop occurs because of different encoding with C++ and Java? Every call to ZeroMQ function succeeded and publishing occurs without an error, but the message does not rich the recipient.

Any other suggestions I can look at?

Comment: The endianess of short/int/long might need care, C++ strings end in a byte 0, Java `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` has no terminating byte 0.

Comment: @JoopEggen, does this mean that for string "ABC" on C++ the length is 4, while on JAVA the length is 3 and therefore the "ABC" != "ABC"? If yes - how do I fix it?

Comment: *when I try to publish something from C++ binary* -- Exactly how are you doing this in C++?  There are so many failed attempts of doing this correctly I see here, like using `sizeof` on a class type, or `strlen` when the data is not null-terminated, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, `auto header = "ABC"; if( zmq_send( m_publisher, header.c_str(), strlen( header.c_str() ), ZMQ_SNDMORE ) == -1 ) { //print error }`. This is my latest attempt. It will be compiled with C++11, hence the `auto` declaration.

Comment: `auto header = "ABC";` -- That's a `const char *`, not a `std::string`.

Comment: @Igor I do not know the code you use, how the C++/Java bridge works you are using. No experience on Android. It it is just communication, everything is easy. Show code here, ensure debugging.